How can I export data from a Thingboard table widget to XLS or CSV and automate email delivery?
Problem Description:
I need to extract data from a table widget in Thingboard and convert it into either XLS or CSV format. Additionally, I want to automate the process of sending this data via email on a regular schedule.
Details:
Extracting Data: The data is displayed in a table widget on Thingboard, and I need a method to fetch this data programmatically.
Converting to XLS/CSV: Once the data is fetched, I need to convert it into either XLS or CSV format for easier analysis and sharing.
Automating Email Delivery: After conversion, I want to automate the sending of this data via email. This should occur at regular intervals (e.g., daily, weekly).
